Convert vimwiki_diary_months to lua
How do you set g.vimwiki_diary_months in lua?
According to :h g.vimwiki_diary_months:
*g:vimwiki_diary_months*

It is a |Dictionary| with the numbers of months and corresponding names. Diary
uses it.

Redefine it in your .vimrc to get localized months in your diary:
let g:vimwiki_diary_months = {
      \ 1: 'Январь', 2: 'Февраль', 3: 'Март',
      \ 4: 'Апрель', 5: 'Май', 6: 'Июнь',
      \ 7: 'Июль', 8: 'Август', 9: 'Сентябрь',
      \ 10: 'Октябрь', 11: 'Ноябрь', 12: 'Декабрь'
      \ }

Default:
let g:vimwiki_diary_months = {
      \ 1: 'January', 2: 'February', 3: 'March',
      \ 4: 'April', 5: 'May', 6: 'June',
      \ 7: 'July', 8: 'August', 9: 'September',
      \ 10: 'October', 11: 'November', 12: 'December'
      \ }

So far, I wrote the following code:
dict = {}
dict[1] = 'Enero'
dict[2] = 'Febrero'
dict[3] = 'Marzo'
dict[4] = 'Abril'
dict[5] = 'Mayo'
dict[6] = 'Junio'
dict[7] = 'Julio'
dict[8] = 'Agosto'
dict[9] = 'Septiembre'
dict[10] = 'Octubre'
dict[11] = 'Noviembre'
dict[12] = 'Diciembre'
vim.g.vimwiki_diary_months =  { dict }

But reports as error:
Vimwiki: Error: The provided value of the option 'g:vimwiki_diary_months' is a list, but expected is a dictionary. See ':h g:vimwiki_diary_months'

Where is the mistake?

I would do:
dict = {
  ['1'] = 'Enero',
  ['2'] = 'Febrero',
  ['3'] = 'Marzo',
  ['4'] = 'Abril',
  ['5'] = 'Mayo',
  ['6'] = 'Junio',
  ['7'] = 'Julio',
  ['8'] = 'Agosto',
  ['9'] = 'Septiembre',
  ['10'] = 'Octubre',
  ['11'] = 'Noviembre',
  ['12'] = 'Diciembre',
}

vim.g.vimwiki_diary_months =  dict

The lua syntax for dictionary with non identifier keys is somehow uncommon.
You have an example in the lua doc about tables:
-- That syntax is more cumbersome, but more flexible too: Both the list-style and the record-style forms are special cases of this more general one. The constructor 
{x=0, y=0}
-- is equivalent to
{["x"]=0, ["y"]=0}

